# Mapping drive to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

Maybe someone can help me with this one. I am able to map a SharePoint folder to a drive just fine , however if I log off then log back in , there is a red X on the drive , if i double click it and put my credentials then it fine again.

My question is , How do I avoid that ?  how can I make it so that when I login, the drive is ready to go and I dont have to click on it and type my password?

Answer (score 0):

Open IE

Tools -> Internet Options -> Security

The its either "Trusted" or "Local Intranet" depending on your settings

Sites -> Advanced (or Add) -> Add

then add `file://*.yourdomainname.com`, or `http://*.yourdomainname.com`

Answer (score 0):

***Create the perfect user first.***
***On a fresh profile***

1. Populate the trusted list in IE with everything required.
2. Open Regedit and extract the keys at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap`

This will be your importable reg file.

***On the profile you wish to provision run the script that.***

First imports the reg file using

`Reg Import "%~dp0\TrustedSites.reg"`

or something similar.

Then opens internet explorer to a SharePoint page, using the UNC path, that everyone in the company should have access to, but still requires O365 credentials.

Sets a pause, so once Internet Explorer has completed loading, you can tell the batch to move on. This can also be done with "sleep". IE must fully load and save the credentials to the page.

Kills ALL open IE instances using

`Taskkill /IM "iexplore.exe" /F`

Then using the following command you can map directly to that SharePoint folder.

`net use <Your drive letter>: "<Full UNC Path>"  /p:yes`

If you have multiple sharable folders add another line like the one above. It will only map drives drive to the resources THE CURRENT USER has privileges to access. All the rest will show as "path not found" or something similar. The script will move one at a time through the resources and map the appropriate drives to the user.